# The new GE blower motor is missing an orange wire, how to connect it properly?

Tags: blower

My old GE blower motor had an orange wire. Unfortunately, the new replacement motor has no orange wire.

The new motor will not start up with just the black, blue, yellow, red, and the 2 browns going to the capacitor.

However there are 4 factory-connected wires coming out and then returning inside the motor: they are yellow to purple, and orange to brown.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: We will need the model number of the old AND new motors to assist.

Comment: Can you post photos of the nameplates on the old and new motors?

Answer (score 1):

The 4 wires coming out of and returning to to motor are for reversing the rotation of the motor. If you unplug them and switch them the rotation will switch. The yellow wire is most likely the common wire. The others are speed taps. Red is low, blue is medium and black is high (usually). The two browns go to the capacitor. I would need to see the wiring diagram to be sure but that is the usual wiring setup on furnaces. The orange wire was most likely medium high.